# Placing shapes along a square spiral

Tags: mathematical-optimization, computational-geometry, code-review

Proposed code example is inspired by the main idea of [this challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/222520/placing-circles-along-a-square-spiral).
Wolfram Language provides great opportunities in computational geometry.
But not all of them are equal in terms of speed and efficiency.
This code provides result similar to the images from the challenge,
but with any custom figures.
I managed to find interesting solutions (and hope it will be useful for those who study   computational geometry with Mathematica)
But it needs further improvement and optimization as noted in the comments.

```
ClearAll;
(*How to avoid Prepend?*)
squareSpiral[num_] := 
  Prepend[ReIm /@ 
    Accumulate@
     Table[I^\[LeftFloor](4*k + 1)^.5 - 1\[RightFloor], {k, 0, 
       num}], {0, 0}];
(*Vertices of custom shape*)
starPolygon[n_, d_] /; n > 4 && 0.01 < d < 1 := 
  With[{pts = 1. CirclePoints[n]}, 
   Table[If[EvenQ@k, d pts[[k]], pts[[k]]], {k, n}]];

moveShape[center_, size_, shape_] := 
  TranslationTransform[center][ScalingTransform[{size, size}][shape]];

(*Such operations as intersection,membership etc.work much faster \
with BoundaryMeshRegion*)
myRegion[pts_, col_] := 
  With[{bnd = Append[Range@Length@pts, 1]}, 
   BoundaryMeshRegion[pts, Line@bnd, BaseStyle -> col]];

(*RegionDisjoint works not properly still in version 13.2*)
isNonIntersect[shape1_, shape2_] := 
  SameQ[RegionIntersection[shape1, shape2], EmptyRegion[2]];

numTrials = 1000; сenters = squareSpiral[numTrials];
numColors = 3; result = ConstantArray[{}, numColors];
initialShape = starPolygon[14, 0.5];
colors = Table[ColorData["DarkRainbow"][x], {x, 0., 1., 1./numColors}];

Monitor[Do[counter = 1;
  index = 1;
  While[index <= Length@сenters, center = сenters[[index]];
   trialShape = 
    myRegion[moveShape[center, Sqrt[1. counter], initialShape], 
     colors[[colorIndex]]];
   (*Start checking with nearby shape.This mabe improved*)
   sorted = SortBy[Flatten@result, RegionDistance[#, center] &];
   (*The check goes to the first False result*)
   If[LengthWhile[sorted, isNonIntersect[#, trialShape] &] == 
     Length@sorted,(*Add approved shape*)
    AppendTo[result[[colorIndex]], trialShape];
    (*Better create function object for reuse*)
    rmf = RegionMember[trialShape];
    (*Delete centers that are inside new approved shape*)
    сenters = DeleteCases[сenters, c_ /; rmf@c];
    counter += 1]; index += 1], {colorIndex, numColors}],colorIndex];

(*Create Manipulate object and GIF presentation*)
(*How to avoid size changing?And create infinite animation*)
m = Manipulate[
   Show[result[[1 ;; k]], Background -> Black, ImageSize -> 300], {k, 
    1, numColors, 1}];
Export["test.gif", m, "ControlAppearance" -> None]
```

[image]

Comment: It seems that the the code missing some part and cann't run in v13.2.

Comment: @cvgmt   Yes, missing fragment and Monitor option added

Comment: You can get a square spiral with builtin features like this:
`squareSpiral[n_] := 
  With[{g = PathGraph[Range@n, GraphLayout -> "DiscreteSpiralEmbedding"]},
   With[{e = GraphEmbedding@g}, # - e[[1]] & /@ e]];`